# Distributed rendering in a CAVE system

Tags: rendering, distributed-computing

I am currently working with CAVE systems and I'm looking into hooking up a pre-exisiting game engine in one. I know this is possible through Unity and the Unreal Engine as there is already research out there showcasing that it has been done.

Right now, I have not decided upon one game engine to use and I'm currently looking around and researching if it is possible with the likes of CryEngine and Valve's Source Engine. The one issue that I am going to face, however, is getting the image to correctly render across all four of the monitors / screens.

Thusly, as a result I have two questions:
 1.Does anyone know of any good research / books on distrubuted rendering? It doesn't need to be specificly for games, just the topic in general would be very useful
 2.Does anyone know if other developers have managed to get Source and the CryEngine to run in a CAVE system? Through all my research I haven't been able to find anything on this, but then my google skills aren't the greatest.

If anyone could spare the time to answer these questions, I'd be extremely greatful.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you share your research later with the rest of the world. We've got one of the biggest CAVE installations in the world here and it might be fun to explore some CryEngine worls inside :)

Answer (score 0):

too late for an answer, but still, you might want to have a look at

- Equalizer: http://www.equalizergraphics.com
- IceT: http://icet.sandia.gov
- Chromium
  (and a few more referenced in related publications, websites)